# Copy specified columns in particular order

Tags: excel, vba

I have 80 or so columns of data. I need just 21 columns.

In my output, I would like the 21 columns to be in a particular order. For example, I want the value from the cell AX2 from my source file to go to A2, BW2 to go to B2, etc.

The source data may differ from month to month and could have as little as 1 row of data or hundreds so I would like this to loop until no data is left.

I got a run time error 424 object required. I have only outlined the rules for two columns but will work on the rest when I get the proper set up.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
   Sheet4.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    row_count = 2
    
    Do While Sheet2.Range("A" & row_count) <> ""
 
    Range("AX2:AX1000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Range("A").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Range("BW2:BW1000").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    Range("B").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    x = x + 1
    
    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
       
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to let us know what issues you're running into with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't go too far. Try this subscript, it asks you to select a workbook, it will open the workbook, copy column B2 to last used Row on Column B, and paste it on the first workbook. Make sure to rename the CopyFromSheet and CopyToSheet on the code. Please read each line and try to understand what it is doing. Let me know if any questions.

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim openFile As FileDialog, wb As Workbook, sourceWb As Workbook
    Dim CopyTo As String, CopyFrom As String
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set openFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    openFile.Title = "Select Source File"
    openFile.Filters.Clear
    openFile.Filters.Add "Excel Files Only", "*.xl*"
    openFile.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
    openFile.Show
    If openFile.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        Set sourceWb = Workbooks.Open(openFile.SelectedItems(1), False, True, , , , True)
        CopyFrom = "CopyFromSheetName"
        CopyTo = "CopyToSheetName"
        lastRow = sourceWb.Sheets(CopyFrom).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(Excel.xlUp).Row
        sourceWb.Sheets(CopyFrom).Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Copy 'You can copy this Row and the Next and add as many as you want to copy the Columns Needed
        wb.Sheets(CopyTo).Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy
    Else
        MsgBox "A file was not selected"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you separate the copy logic from the setup of which columns to copy.  That way it will be much easier to manage the setup.

In this code I have hard coded to Columns Pairs.  Alternatively, you could put that data on a sheet and read it in.

```
Sub Demo()
    'declare all your variables
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim CP() As Variant 'Column Pairs array
    Dim idx As Long

    'Set up an array of Source and Destination columns
    ReDim CP(1 To 21, 1 To 2) 'Adjust size to suit number of column pairs
    CP(1, 1) = "AX": CP(1, 2) = "A"
    CP(2, 1) = "BW": CP(2, 2) = "B"
    'and so on

    ' Source and Destination don't have to be in the same Workbook
    ' This code assumes the Source (and Destination) worksbooks are already open
    '    You can add code to open them if required
    ' If the data is in the same book as the code, use ThisWorkbook
    ' If the data is in a different book from the code,
    '    specify the book like Application.Workbooks("BookName.xlsx")
    '    or use ActiveWorkbook

    'Update the names to your sheet names
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceSheetName")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DestSheetName")


    ' Notice that form here on the code is independent of the Sheet and Column names
    'Loop the column pairs array
    For idx = 1 To UBound(CP, 1)
        'if the entry is not blank
        If CP(idx, 1) <> vbNullString Then
            'Get reference to source column cell on row 2
            Set rSource = wsSource.Columns(CP(idx, 1)).Cells(2, 1)
            'If that cell is not empty
            If Not IsEmpty(rSource) Then
                'If the next cell is not empty
                If Not IsEmpty(rSource.Offset(1, 0)) Then
                    'extend range down to first blank cell
                    Set rSource = wsSource.Range(rSource, rSource.End(xlDown))
                End If
                'Get a reference to the destination range, from row 2, same size as source
                Set rDest = wsDest.Columns(CP(idx, 2)).Cells(2, 1).Resize(rSource.Rows.Count)

                'Copy the values
                rDest.Value = rSource.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! This is exactly what I was looking for and was super easy / quick to run.

Comment: Hey Chris, I am getting now a run-time error '9' outlining "Subscript out of range" . Debugger shows it is at this point     'Update the names to your sheet names
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")